# Expected Unqualified-Id before 'delete' function

Tags: c++

I wrote a C++ program, this error appeared and I can not find the cause. Can anybody help me. This function is used to delete element i-th from a linked list, even tried my best but I can't find the reason.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int value;
    node * next;
};

typedef struct node list;

list* head = NULL;
int list_length = 0;

bool empty(){
    return (head == NULL);
}

void delete(int i){
    if(i>list_length) return;
    if(empty()) return;

    int count = 0;
    list* curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL && count < i-1){
        curr = curr -> next;
        count++;
    }
    list* temp = curr -> next;
    curr next = temp -> next;
    list_length--;
}

int main(){
}
```

Comment: "this error appeared" - What error? And do you know how to use a debugger to find out exactly where the error occurs?

Comment: The error that I mentioned in title of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a method called delete but [delete is a keyword in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/).

Answer (score 4):

[`delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) is a reserved keyword in C++. You have to rename your function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in this code, you have named your function `delete` but [delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/delete) is a [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) in *C++*, the second problem is this line in the `delete` function:

```
curr next = temp -> next;
```

which looks like it should be:

```
curr->next = temp -> next;
```

Answer (score 0):

delete is a reserved keyword in C++. After renaming your function, it works.